# WatchOS is not getting callback in didReceiveUserInfo from iPhone to Watch

Tags: synchronization, watchkit, watchos-2, watchconnectivity, wcsession

Let me clear first that, everything was working perfectly. But from last two days I am facing very weird scenario, I am able to sendUserInfo from WatchOS to iOS but reverse is not happening.

Even I am not getting any error anywhere. I tried to restart, reinstall and repair, but still the same issue is there. Does anyone have the idea to deal with this ?

Comment: Sounds likely to be a bug in the system. You should file a bug report with Apple

Comment: But Other apps are working fine.. So i dont think its issue of System.